# can't download any torrent from different softwares

Tags: bittorrent

I tried to download several torrent files in several torrent softwares like deluge and transmission and they stuck 0% and don't connect to peers although they worked very well a week ago

Comment: If you made no changes, then it seems like a network connection or ISP issue.

Comment: Are you sure there are any seeds/peers for this torrent? Try to download the content of those torrent files on another machine.

Comment: It was found to be an ISP issue ,thanks for your help :D